# how to remove postgresql and phppgadmin from xampp stack

Tags: lamp, postgresql

I installed lampp from https://bitnami.com/stack/lamp on my pc running ubuntu 14.04
i also installed the postgresql addon too from https://bitnami.com/stack/postgresql

Currently i can't seem to login and have messed up my configuration.
I want to totally remove the postgresql addon

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just remove them from webroot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure it out.
PostgreSql module is installed in the directory /opt/lampp/postgresql

To remove it just run the command

```
sudo /opt/lampp/postgresql/uninstall
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to nuke by using the command

sudo dpkg --purge postgresql-XXX

In the place of XXX add the version.